# Cyrillic names in transliteration

Tags: transliteration

I wonder, if there is any adequate and up-to-date guide on transliteration of Cyrillic names. All I have read seem rather inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: There are [many different systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian). Choose one and stick with it. I think it would probably be subjective / Primarily Opinion-based for ELU to pronounce on *which* system you should adopt, but you'd have to seriously consider the [American Library Association & Library of Congress "romanization for Russian"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALA-LC_romanization_for_Russian) standard.

Comment: It's definitely inconsistent and confusing. [Math journals](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/help/cyrillic.pdf) have one system (which I believe nearly all math journals use), the [US government](http://moscow.usembassy.gov/transliteration_e.html) has a different system, and I am sure there are several more systems around.

Comment: If you're writing for some community which consistently uses one system of transliteration, then you should use that system.

Comment: Plus, there are differences in the Cyrillic alphabets used by various languages. There's even a Cyrillic alphabet for Eskimo, which is going a bit far, I think.

Comment: See also [What is the most common transliteration/romanization standard of Cyrillic?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/13368/7864) on Russian Language SE.